# Replace a substring by a rxjs countdowntimer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to implement a countdowntimer using rxjs in my angular 12 application. In my ts I have :

```
let timeLeft$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  map(x => this.calcTimeDiff(orderCutOffTime)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

calcTimeDiff() will return seconds, minutes and hours;

I have to create a string out of this and display that in the HTML. Basically replace an existing word in the string with timeLeft$ which will be a countdowntimer to be shown in the HTML.

Something like :
this.orderCutOffMessage = someString.replace('Down', timeLeft$)

https://henrikmassow.medium.com/implement-a-countdown-timer-with-rxjs-in-angular-61600d1af00c

orderCutOffTime = "1645567200000" // Unix timestamp in milliseconds

```
private calcTimeDiff(cutOffTime: any): timeComponents {
const finalCutOffTime = (cutOffTime).valueOf();
const milliSecondsInASecond = 1000;
const hoursInADay = 24;
const minutesInAnHour = 60;
const secondsInAMinute = 60;
const timeDifference = finalCutOffTime - Date.now();

const hoursToFinalCutOffTime = Math.floor(
  (timeDifference /
    (milliSecondsInASecond * minutesInAnHour * secondsInAMinute)) %
  hoursInADay
);

const minutesToFinalCutOffTime = Math.floor(
  (timeDifference / (milliSecondsInASecond * minutesInAnHour)) %
  secondsInAMinute
);

const secondsToFinalCutOffTime =
  Math.floor(timeDifference / milliSecondsInASecond) % secondsInAMinute;


return { secondsToFinalCutOffTime, minutesToFinalCutOffTime, hoursToFinalCutOffTime };
```

}

Comment: Can you share more code? Like: full `calcTimeDiff` method, the initialization/changes of `orderCutOffTime` var and any relevant code to put this into context?

Comment: Hi @MishaMashina I have updated the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share an example of timeLeft value before return in calcTimeDiff? What do you do with timeLeft - display it in html like in the linked example? Or is your html different? Do you get any errors? Trying to figure out where exactly is the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-znbvdb. It's basicly almost like the one in the link you shared, except that the names of the vars have been changed, one var discarded (days) and everything put in one .ts file. Please let me know if that's what you are looking for. Your `orderCutOffTime` has been hard-coded, but you are probably getting it in some subscription so you can tweak it. Also, `timeString` propably comes from subscription too.

Comment: I have the following string as an api response : "I have the following string as a json response "Order in {000} for early shipping".
I have to replace the {000} part with this.timeLeft$ and display the updated string in the HTML. So for the user it will be something like "Order in 2hr 1mm 50s for early shipping".  I can get the timer in HTML but the problem is I need to have the string completed with the timer in the .ts file.

Comment: Ok check the link again, I've changed the code.